# What hardware is needed to send an SMS from a computer?

Tags: hardware, telephony

I have a Windows 10 desktop computer (with no SIM card) with a program installed that lets me send an SMS message when a certain event fires [...].

The program lets me choose my COM1 interface as the output interface for the message.

What physical hardware would I need to send an SMS from the desktop computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [GSM modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_modem). In the '90s I had a mobile phone that could act as one over a serial port.

Today, to programmatically send SMS, most people will use a web service (such as [Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-phone-number-as-subscriber.html) or [Twilio MessageX](https://www.twilio.com/messaging/sms)) instead of dedicated hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You need a GSM (Global System for Mobile communication) module.

There are USB, network, and serial connection GSM modules.

Note that some GSM modules won't let you send SMS messages, you need to verify that they implement the SMS protocol.

Additionally, you can check if they apply the MMS protocol, which would let you send multimedia files.

Another thing you should make sure of is that the GSM module might not let you send SMS messages via code, and you will need to use an IP webpage to do so.